# How to convert columns into one datetime column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where the first 3 columns are 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'YEAR'

In each column there is an integer.
Is there a Pythonic way to convert all three columns into datetimes while there are in the dataframe?

From:

```
M    D    Y    Apples   Oranges
5    6  1990      12        3
5    7  1990      14        4
5    8  1990      15       34
5    9  1990      23       21
```

into:

```
Datetimes    Apples   Oranges
1990-6-5        12        3
1990-7-5        14        4
1990-8-5        15       34
1990-9-5        23       21
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In 0.13 (coming very soon), this is heavily optimized and quite fast (but still pretty fast in 0.12); both orders of magnitude faster than looping

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   M  D     Y  Apples  Oranges
0  5  6  1990      12        3
1  5  7  1990      14        4
2  5  8  1990      15       34
3  5  9  1990      23       21

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]: 
M          int64
D          int64
Y          int64
Apples     int64
Oranges    int64
dtype: object

# in 0.12, use this
In [5]: pd.to_datetime((df.Y*10000+df.M*100+df.D).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d')

# in 0.13 the above or this will work
In [5]: pd.to_datetime(df.Y*10000+df.M*100+df.D,format='%Y%m%d')
Out[5]: 
0   1990-05-06 00:00:00
1   1990-05-07 00:00:00
2   1990-05-08 00:00:00
3   1990-05-09 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, can you explain what the purposed of the *10000 and the *100 are?

Nevermind, the purpose is to convert 2011, 5, 3, into 20110503 which can easily be read. 

Thanks!!

Comment: yep - this is in fact the fastest method because these are vectorized numeric operations and the conversion to datetime doesn't round trip thru strings

Comment: I'd be interested to see whether you get better results from `pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df.Y, month=df.M, day=df.D))`

Comment: @holdenweb: according to `%timeit`, they're approximately the same - the numerical version is maybe 5-10% faster on the dataset I used. I will use the dict version, because it's more readable.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115465/how-to-convert-year-month-day-hour-minute-columns-into-a-single-datetime-colu/75118182#75118182

Answer (score 145):

In version `0.18.1` you can use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), but:

- The names of the columns have to be `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute` and `second`:
- Minimal columns are `year`, `month` and `day`

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3],
                    'day': [4, 5],
                    'hour': [2, 3],
                    'minute': [10, 30],
                    'second': [21,25]})
    
print df
   day  hour  minute  month  second  year
0    4     2      10      2      21  2015
1    5     3      30      3      25  2016

print pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]

print pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']])
0   2015-02-04 02:00:00
1   2016-03-05 03:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

print pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']])
0   2015-02-04 02:10:00
1   2016-03-05 03:30:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]

print pd.to_datetime(df)
0   2015-02-04 02:10:21
1   2016-03-05 03:30:25
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Another solution is convert to `dictionary`:

```
print df
   M  D     Y  Apples  Oranges
0  5  6  1990      12        3
1  5  7  1990      14        4
2  5  8  1990      15       34
3  5  9  1990      23       21

print pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df.Y, month=df.M, day=df.D))
0   1990-05-06
1   1990-05-07
2   1990-05-08
3   1990-05-09
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: even (slightly) faster than the suggested one, because we're even dropping the minimal arithmetics, thanks jezrael!

Comment: Leaving aside the performance discussion, I find the conversion to `dict` to be the easiest on the eyes.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a alternative which uses [NumPy datetime64 and timedelta64 arithmetic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html). It appears to be a bit faster for small DataFrames and much faster for larger DataFrames:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'M':[1,2,3,4], 'D':[6,7,8,9], 'Y':[1990,1991,1992,1993]})
#    D  M     Y
# 0  6  1  1990
# 1  7  2  1991
# 2  8  3  1992
# 3  9  4  1993

y = np.array(df['Y']-1970, dtype='<M8[Y]')
m = np.array(df['M']-1, dtype='<m8[M]')
d = np.array(df['D']-1, dtype='<m8[D]')
dates2 = pd.Series(y+m+d)
# 0   1990-01-06
# 1   1991-02-07
# 2   1992-03-08
# 3   1993-04-09
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
In [214]: df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

In [215]: %timeit pd.to_datetime((df['Y']*10000+df['M']*100+df['D']).astype('int'), format='%Y%m%d')
100 loops, best of 3: 4.87 ms per loop

In [216]: %timeit pd.Series(np.array(df['Y']-1970, dtype='<M8[Y]')+np.array(df['M']-1, dtype='<m8[M]')+np.array(df['D']-1, dtype='<m8[D]'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 839 µs per loop
```

---

Here's a helper function to make this easier to use:

```
def combine64(years, months=1, days=1, weeks=None, hours=None, minutes=None,
              seconds=None, milliseconds=None, microseconds=None, nanoseconds=None):
    years = np.asarray(years) - 1970
    months = np.asarray(months) - 1
    days = np.asarray(days) - 1
    types = ('<M8[Y]', '<m8[M]', '<m8[D]', '<m8[W]', '<m8[h]',
             '<m8[m]', '<m8[s]', '<m8[ms]', '<m8[us]', '<m8[ns]')
    vals = (years, months, days, weeks, hours, minutes, seconds,
            milliseconds, microseconds, nanoseconds)
    return sum(np.asarray(v, dtype=t) for t, v in zip(types, vals)
               if v is not None)

In [437]: combine64(df['Y'], df['M'], df['D'])
Out[437]: array(['1990-01-06', '1991-02-07', '1992-03-08', '1993-04-09'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: I think this, or this functionality at least, would be a nice enhancement for pandas. We should just figure out an API.

Comment: Yeah, having to do things like `*10000` or `-1970` is silly.  We should definitely be able to combine standard time types in much simpler way.  (And if there *is* a better way but none of us know it, then there's at least a doc bug..)

Answer (score 6):

I re-approached the problem and I think I found a solution. I initialized the csv file in the following way:

```
pandas_object = DataFrame(read_csv('/Path/to/csv/file', parse_dates=True, index_col = [2,0,1] ))
```

Where the:

```
index_col = [2,0,1]
```

represents the columns of the [year, month, day]

Only problem now is that now I have three new index columns, one represent the year, another the month, and another the day.

Comment: try `parse_dates=[[2,0,1]]` (note the double brackets.  Have a look at the doctstring on `read_csv` for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the dataframe to strings for easy string concatenation:

```
df=df.astype(str)
```

then convert to datetime, specify the format:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.Y+df.M+df.D,format="%Y%m%d")
```

which replaces the index rather than creating a new column.

Answer (score 2):

Even better way to do is as below:

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime

dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')

date=dataset.apply(lambda x: datetime.date(int(x['Yr']), x['Mo'], x['Dy']),axis=1)

date = pd.to_datetime(date)

dataset = dataset.drop(columns=['Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy'])

dataset.insert(0, 'Date', date)

dataset.head()
```

---

Comment: Please, add some description or comments on what you doing in this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [pd.to_datetime(str(a)+str(b)+str(c),
                 format='%m%d%Y'
                ) for a,b,c in zip(df.M, df.D, df.Y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you've got a dictionary `foo` with each column of dates in parallel. If so, here's your one liner:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> foo = {"M": [1,2,3], "D":[30,30,21], "Y":[1980,1981,1982]}
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Datetime": [datetime(y,m,d) for y,m,d in zip(foo["Y"],foo["M"],foo["D"])]})
```

The real guts of it are this bit:

```
>>> [datetime(y,m,d) for y,m,d in zip(foo["Y"],foo["M"],foo["D"])]
[datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1981, 2, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1982, 3, 21, 0, 0)]
```

This is the sort of thing `zip` was made for. It takes parallel lists and turns them into tuples. Then they get tuple unpacked (the `for y,m,d in` bit) by the list comprehension there, then fed into the `datetime` object constructor.

`pandas` seems happy with the datetime objects.