# New columns with day and month one day later than existing day and month, and offset by one row

Tags: date, pandas

I have a DataFrame with columns for `YEAR` `END_DAY` and `END_MONTH` as integers and I need to set new columns for `START_DAY` and `START_MONTH`. The start dates should be one day later than the end dates in the previous row (the first row should have `START_DAY` and `START_MONTH` both equal to 1).

My problem is that I'm having trouble getting pandas to create a date column which I can then apply a timedelta to. Here's my offending line:

```
aws['END_DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime(aws['YEAR'],
                                     aws['END_MONTH'],
                                     aws['END_DAY'], format="%m,%d")
```

And the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 136, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg.values, box=False)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 115, in _convert_listlike
    result = tslib.array_strptime(arg, format, coerce=coerce)
File "tslib.pyx", line 1255, in pandas.tslib.array_strptime (pandas\tslib.c:20089)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

EDIT: The part of the problem above is solved by passing a string as in @Roman Pekar's answer (or the linked duplicate), but they don't address the other part of the question. I have a solution for that (below), but I would be interested in any better options.

```
aws['END_DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime((aws['YEAR'] * 10000 +
                                      aws['END_MONTH'] * 100 +
                                      aws['END_DAY']).astype(str),
                                     format="%Y%m%d")
aws['START_DATE'] = aws['END_DATE'] + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
aws['START_DATE'] = aws['START_DATE'].shift(1)
aws['START_DATE'][0] = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
aws['START_DAY'] = aws['START_DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
aws['START_MONTH'] = aws['START_DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert columns into one datetime column in pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350806/how-to-convert-columns-into-one-datetime-column-in-pandas)

Comment: That one solves the first part of the question, though doesn't solve the offset by a row part.

Comment: Can you then update your question using that info, and specify the second part?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, `to_datetime` expects string and you have ints. You can create new column like:

```
aws['END_DATE']  = aws.apply(lambda x: datetime(x['YEAR'], x['END_MONTH'], x['END_DAY']), axis=1)
```