# How to Parse 0 hour with dateutil

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-dateutil

I'm trying to merge my dataframe columns which contain time info (UTC) into a single column containing datetime object/string. The columns of my df are like this:

```
YY MM DD HH
98 12 05 11
98 12 05 10
```

So, I would like a single column containing that time information.

What I've tried so far:

I've merged into a string so that I can parse them into a datetime object by

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d_test = (list(df[0].map(str) + " " + df[1].map(str) + " " + df[2].map(str) 
+ " " + df[3].map(str)))
```

Now I just have to parse the list of date strings

```
parse_d = []
for d in d_test:
    parse_d.append(parse(d))
```

But this is raising me an "unknown string error". I looked into it and it arrises because some of the dates are like:

```
d_test[5] = '98 12 5 0'
```

I've tried reading the detailed documentation of dateutil (https://labix.org/python-dateutil) and what I understood is that I've to make a dictionary specifying the timezone as key (UTC in my case) and that might solve the error.

```
tzinfo ={}
parse(d_test[5], tzinfo=tzinfo)
```

Maybe, I'm missing something very basic but I'm not able to understand how to create this dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you *know* the format of a string, you don't need to use `dateutil.parser.parse` to parse it, because you can use `datetime.strptime` with a specified string.

In this case, the only slightly unfortunate thing is that you have 2-digit years, some of which are from before 2000. In this case, I'd probably do something like this:

```
cent_21_mask =  df['YY'] < 50
df.loc[:, 'YY'] = df.loc[:, 'YY'] + 1900
df.loc[cent_21_mask, 'YY'] = df.loc[cent_21_mask, 'YY'] + 100
```

Once you've done that, you can use one of the solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350806/how-to-convert-columns-into-one-datetime-column-in-pandas) (specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131/467366)) to convert your individual datetime columns into pandas Timestamps / datetimes.

If these are in UTC, you then use [`pandas.Series.tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) with `'UTC'` to get timezone-aware datetimes.

Putting it all together:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[98, 12, 5, 11],
     [98, 12, 5, 10],
     [4, 12, 5, 00]],
     columns=['YY', 'MM', 'DD', 'HH'])

# Convert 2-digit years to 4-digit years
cent_21_mask =  df['YY'] < 50
df.loc[:, 'YY'] = df.loc[:, 'YY'] + 1900
df.loc[cent_21_mask, 'YY'] = df.loc[cent_21_mask, 'YY'] + 100


# Retrieve the date columns and rename them
col_renames = {'YY': 'year', 'MM': 'month', 'DD': 'day', 'HH': 'hour'}
dt_subset = df.loc[:, list(col_renames.keys())].rename(columns=col_renames)
dt_series = pd.to_datetime(dt_subset)

# Convert to UTC
dt_series = dt_series.dt.tz_localize('UTC')

# Result:
# 0   1998-12-05 11:00:00+00:00
# 1   1998-12-05 10:00:00+00:00
# 2   2004-12-05 00:00:00+00:00
# dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Also, to clarify two things about this statement:

> I've tried reading the detailed documentation of dateutil (https://labix.org/python-dateutil) and what I understood is that I've to make a dictionary specifying the timezone as key (UTC in my case) and that might solve the error.

1. The correct documentation for `python-dateutil` is now https://dateutil.readthedocs.io.
2. If you are using `parse`, in your situation there is no reason to add UTC into a dictionary and pass it to `tzinfos`. If you know that your datetimes are going to be naive but that they represent times in UTC, parse them as normal to get naive datetimes, then use `datetime.replace(dateutil.tz.tzutc())` to get aware datetimes. The `tzinfos` dictionary is for when the timezone information is actually represented in the string.

An example of what to do when you have strings representing UTC that *don't* contain timezone information:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil import tz

dt = parse('1998-12-05 11:00')
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())
```

Comment: In the case when I don't have time in UTC, how do I make use of tzinfo? For eg, the doc says in an example tzinfos = {"BRST": -10800}. What does 10800 represent here?

Comment: 10800 is the number of seconds in the offset. That will find strings with `BRST` in them an assign them to UTC-3.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you parse the date in this format?

```
parse("98/12/05 00h")
```

Comment: I figured if I add an "h" to my date string then I can parse it using dateutil.parse.parse