# How to merge month and year columns to get single mm-yyyy column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df like this:

```
Sr.  lwd_month lwd_year
1     3        2015
2     6        2018
3.    9        2017
4.    NaN      NaN
5.    5        2015
```

How can I merge this two columns to get dataframe like below?:

```
Sr.  lwd_month   lwd_Year   MonthYear
1     3          2015    03-2015
2     6          2018     06-2018
3.    9          2017     09-2017
4.    NaN        NaN      NaT
5.    5          2015     05-2015
6.    3          NaN      NaT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need columns names with lowercase `year` and `month` and pandas version `0.18.1+`.

Then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert [by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131/2901002) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for strings:

```
df['MonthYear']=pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)[['year','month','day']]).dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
print (df)
   Sr.  month    year MonthYear
0  1.0    3.0  2015.0   03-2015
1  2.0    6.0  2018.0   06-2018
2  3.0    9.0  2017.0   09-2017
3  4.0    NaN     NaN       NaT
4  5.0    5.0  2015.0   05-2015

print (type(df.loc[0, 'MonthYear']))
<class 'str'>
```

Similar for month period use [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['MonthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)[['year','month','day']]).dt.to_period('m')
print (df)
   Sr.  month    year MonthYear
0  1.0    3.0  2015.0   2015-03
1  2.0    6.0  2018.0   2018-06
2  3.0    9.0  2017.0   2017-09
3  4.0    NaN     NaN       NaT
4  5.0    5.0  2015.0   2015-05

print (type(df.loc[0, 'MonthYear']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'>
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd method giving an error `to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [month,year] is missing`

Comment: I think 3rd not working because there might be a cases where month is present and year is NaN.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - OK, try `df['MonthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(Day=1)[['Year','Month','Day']].rename(columns=str.lower)).dt.strftime('%m-%Y')`

Comment: my actual column names are different from given in question. If I'm not wrong I have to replace them with `Year` and `Month` which I'm doing.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - Yes, if repalce them by lowercase it will working nice.

Comment: still giving same error. I edited column names please check.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - need columns names `year`, `month`.

Comment: Thanks. changing column name helped here.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just this:

```
df['MonthYear'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month']].assign(Day=1)).dt.strftime('%m-%Y')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Sr.  Month    Year MonthYear
0  1.0    3.0  2015.0   03-2015
1  2.0    6.0  2018.0   06-2018
2  3.0    9.0  2017.0   09-2017
3  4.0    NaN     NaN       NaT
4  5.0    5.0  2015.0   05-2015
```