# Combine year, month and day in Python to create a date

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataframe that consists of separate columns for year, month and day. I tried to combine these individual columns into one date using:

```
df['myDt']=pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])
```

only to get the following error: "to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing". Not sure what this means....I'm already supplying the relevant columns. 
On checking the datatypes, I found that they Year, Month and Day columns are int64. Would that be causing an issue? 
Thanks,
Chet

Thank you all for posting. As suggested, I'm posting the sample data set first:
           `Value        mm  yy     dd
Date

2018-11-30  88.550067   11  2018    1
2018-12-31  88.906290   12  2018    1
2019-01-31  88.723000   1   2019    1
2019-02-28  89.509179   2   2019    1
2019-03-31  90.049161   3   2019    1
2019-04-30  90.523100   4   2019    1
2019-05-31  90.102484   5   2019    1
2019-06-30  91.179400   6   2019    1
2019-07-31  90.963570   7   2019    1
2019-08-31  92.159170   8   2019    1`

The data source is:https://www.quandl.com/data/EIA/STEO_NGPRPUS_M
I imported the data as follows:
1. import quandl (used conda install first)
2. Used Quandl's Python code:

data=quandl.get("EIA/STEO_NGPRPUS_M", authtoken="TOKEN","2005-01-01","2005-12-31")
4. Just to note, the original data comes only with the Value column, and DateTime as index. I extracted and created the mm,yy and dd columns (month, year, and dd is a column vector set to 1)
All I'm trying to do is create another column called "first of the month" - so for each day of each month, the column will just show "MM/YY/1". I'm going to try out all the suggestions below shortly and get back to you guys. Thanks!!

Comment: can you post a full code?

Comment: Post a part of your data set with dputs. Otherwise it is not possible to get your issue....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Solution

You could use `datetime.datetime` along with `.apply()`.

```py
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)
date = d.date()
```

### For `pandas.to_datetime(df)`

It looks like your code is fine. See [`pandas.to_datetime` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [How to convert columns into one datetime column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350806/how-to-convert-columns-into-one-datetime-column-in-pandas).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3],
                   'day': [4, 5]})
pd.to_datetime(df[["year", "month", "day"]])
```

**Output**:

```
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

### What if your YEAR, MONTH and DAY columns have different headers?

Let's say your YEAR, MONTH and DAY columns are labeled as `yy`, `mm` and `dd` respectively. And you prefer to keep your column names unchanged. In that case you could do it as follows.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'yy': [2015, 2016],
                   'mm': [2, 3],
                   'dd': [4, 5]})
df2 = df[["yy", "mm", "dd"]].copy()
df2.columns = ["year", "month", "day"]
pd.to_datetime(df2)
```

**Output**:

```
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: A good package for processing date time is `lubridate`. Use e.g. the `ymd()` function for your issue.

Comment: @CypherX - your suggestion looked the easiest, so I started with that. I've seen the link you shared yesterday. I found the issue...the column names HAVE to be "year", "month", "day", and not my own abbreviations (I was using 'yy', 'mm','dd'). I tried that and it worked.

Comment: @Chet Thank you for accepting my answer. You need not change your original column names. Since, `pd.to_datetime()` requires `year`, `month`, `day`, you could try something like what I suggested in the last part that I added now.

Comment: @CypherX - thanks sir, I'll take a look at that and let you know!

Comment: @CypherX - this is interesting.....while it works, it's also an extra step....maybe this is something that GitHub should take note of......it shouldn't matter what the column names are as long as the vectors are provided in the right order (e.g. excel's date (year,month,day) doesn't care about column names.....just a thought. Thanks for this very interesting suggestion.

Comment: ```df2 = df[["yy", "mm", "dd"]].copy()```
results in 
```AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'columns'```
creating a new df without copy works for me

Answer (score 6):

Here is a two liner:

```
df['dateInt']=df['year'].astype(str) + df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)+ df['day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateInt'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

**Output**

```
    year  month day dateInt     Date
0   2015    5   20  20150520    2015-05-20
1   2016    6   21  20160621    2016-06-21
2   2017    7   22  20170722    2017-07-22
3   2018    8   23  20180823    2018-08-23
4   2019    9   24  20190924    2019-09-24
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Thanks for your help - I ended up trying CypherX's code below, and I realized my error was that I was using my own abbreviations for the column names - Python wants them to be specific. I changed accordingly and it works now.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `apply` method as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['myDt'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(f"{int(row.year)}-{int(row.month)}-{int(row.day)}", '%Y-%m-%d'), axis=1)
```

**Running Example:**

```py
>>> d = {'year': list(range(2015, 2020)), 'month': list(range(5, 10)), 'day': >> list(range(20, 25))}
>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>> df

    year    month   day myDt
0   2015    5       20  2015-05-20
1   2016    6       21  2016-06-21
2   2017    7       22  2017-07-22
3   2018    8       23  2018-08-23
4   2019    9       24  2019-09-24
```

Comment: Thanks sir. This gave me an error that I can't figure out. I tried the code suggested by @CypherX at the bottom and that worked. Seems like Python wants very specific names for columns; I can't use my own abbreviations. Learning!

Comment: @Chet, no worries. I wonder what is the error you are getting, if you can provide some feedback I will give you further help.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf - the error I get sir is pasted below. Please bear in mind that I'm VERY new to Python....so I don't understand all that's going on...it's all trial and error for me at this time. " ValueError: ("time data '2005.0-1.0-1.0' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'", 'occurred at index 2005-01-31 00:00:00') "

Comment: @Chet, I updated my answer. The problem is that `year`, `month`, and `day` columns are `float`s, and they should be `int`s. Use `int` built-in to fix it.

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf  - thanks sir....this works for me as well. It's a little hard to read (given my newbie status)..but I'm keeping this in my repository of useful code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Add and calculate a new Calculated_Date column

df['Calculated_Date'] = df[['year', 'month', 'day']].apply(lambda x: '{}-{}-{}'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2]), axis=1)

df['Calculated_Date'].head()


#Parse your Calculated_Date column into a datetime obj (not needed; but if you need to parse)

df['Calculated_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Calculated_Date'])

df['Calculated_Date'].head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072805/11671779) from @lmiguelvargasf, sometimes you want to save as `datetime` format. Furthermore, using `apply` (IMHO) is better if other column is exist with some value (something like sales for the example).

```py
import datetime

df['dt'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime(int(row.yy),
                                                  int(row.mm),
                                                  int(row.dd)), axis=1)
df.head()
```

Note: my example only working if the `yy` value is in `2022` for example. If your `yy` value is `21`, you need to modify such as `2000 + int(row.yy)`.