# dataframe python converting to weekday from year, month, day

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am trying to add new Dataframe column by manipulating other cols.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
from pandas import read_csv
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('PRSA_data_2010.1.1-2014.12.31.csv')
df.head()
```

[image]

When I am trying to manipulate

```
df['weekday']= np.int(datetime.datetime(df.year, df.month, df.day).weekday())
```

I am keep getting error cannot convert the series to class 'int'.

Can anyone tell me a reason behind this and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Convert [columns to datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131) and then to weekdays by [`Series.dt.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html):

```
df['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']].dt.weekday
```

Or convert columns to datetime column in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('PRSA_data_2010.1.1-2014.12.31.csv',
                  date_parser=lambda y,m,d: y + '-' + m + '-' + d, 
                  parse_dates={'datetimes':['year','month','day']})

df['weekday'] = df['datetimes'].dt.weekday
```