# How to add padding zeros to a datetime object in Python?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, indexing

I have a file which looks like this:

```
London  XXX Europe  2020    9   7   0   0   0   2   2020    9   7   0   11  35  2   57
Tanger  XXX Africa  2020    9   7   0   29  54  2   2020    9   7   23  57  16  2   29
Doha    XXX Asia    2020    9   7   0   57  23  2   2020    9   7   23  58  48  2   11
```

I'am trying to combine index `3,4,5,6,7,8` into a datetimeobject with `Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second.` I try to do the same with `end_time`. However, the zeros in my file seem to produce some weird output.

**This is my code:**

```
path = r'c:\data\EK\Desktop\Python Microsoft Visual Studio\Extra\test_datetime.txt'

with open(path, 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        start_time = (row[3] + row[4] + row[5] + row[6] + row[7] + row[8])  
        end_time = (row[10] + row[11] + row[12] + row[13] + row[14] + row[15])

        start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        end_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

        print(start_time)
        print(end_time)
```

**This is my current output:**

```
2020-09-07 00:00:00
2020-09-07 01:13:05
2020-09-07 02:09:54
2020-09-07 23:57:16
2020-09-07 05:07:23
2020-09-07 23:58:48
```

**This is my expected output:**

```
2020-09-07 00:00:00
2020-09-07 00:11:35
2020-09-07 00:29:54
2020-09-07 23:57:16
2020-09-07 00:57:23
2020-09-07 23:58:48
```

Comment: is using pandas an option?

Comment: Why are you using `strptime()` instead of just creating a `datetime` object directly from the values in the file?

Comment: @EzerK no, preferablly not. I want to make it work with my current code.

Comment: @Barmar I have not really though about it...

Comment: +1 for using `pandas` - if you want to dig deep, skip using `csv` as well and write your own parser. But why not enjoy some convenience? e.g. have a look at [convert columns into one datetime column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19350806/10197418).

Comment: the format `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` will mess up everything, digits joint with digits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you concatenate the fields like `row[3] + row[4] + row[5] + row[6] + row[7] + row[8]` all the single-digit fields have no leading zeroes, so they aren't parsed properly with `strptime()`.

You could use a string formatting function to add leading zeroes, but there's no reason to use `strptime()` in the first place. Just call `datetime.datetime()` to create an object directly from the values.

```
start_time = datetime.datetime(*map(int, row[3:9]))
end_time = datetime.datetime(*map(int, row[10:16]))
```

Comment: thanks. This looks good. Can you just explain what the `*` and the `map` function just did?

Comment: `map()` calls a function on all the elements of a list and returns all the results. So this converts all the strings in that list to integers. And `*` spreads a list into separate arguments to the function.

Comment: So can I assume that this will always work 100%?

Comment: I'm not going to bet my life on it, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: It should work as long as the columns in your CSV are in the same order as the arguments to `datetime.datetime()`