# ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Tags: pandas, numpy, date, k-means, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to plot with kmeans, but I'm stuck because one column is with dates, and it's making a lot of problems. (you can see in the screenshot the data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rffTC.png))

I've alreay used to_datetime, so what now I should do?

how to pass this problem and plot it?

Thank you in advance!

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


AAPL= pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv', header=0, squeeze=True)
#sd=store_data.head(100)

x = pd.to_datetime(AAPL.iloc[:, [0,1]],dayfirst=True)
print(x)
kmeans4 = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
y_kmeans4 = kmeans4.fit_predict(x)
print(y_kmeans4)
print(kmeans4.cluster_centers_)

plt.scatter(x[:,0],x[:,1],c=y_kmeans4,cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(kmeans4.cluster_centers_[:,0] ,kmeans4.cluster_centers_[:,1],color='black')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need select first column only:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(AAPL.iloc[:, 0],dayfirst=True)
```

If use:

```
x = pd.to_datetime(AAPL.iloc[:, [0,1]],dayfirst=True)
```

it select first and second column and raise error, because `pd.to_datetime` working only if passed columns `year, month, days` like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131/2901002).

Comment: but x needs to be both this columns. The predict is on both columns

Comment: @Bordento22 - Do you try it? It select first column.