# How to create a mask with 3 conditions and using numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and I need to filter this by date, a have 3 columns with year, month and day. I try use:

```
mask = (df_atleti_cadiz['year']== 2021) | (df_atleti_cadiz['month']==1) | (df_atleti_cadiz['day']== 31)
```

And after create a new df using:

```
df_atleti_cadiz_match = df_atleti_cadiz[mask]
```

But don't have sucess

Comment: [How to convert columns into one datetime column in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350806/how-to-convert-columns-into-one-datetime-column-in-pandas) - make a datetime Series; compare the Series to your condition; use the resulting boolean Series for the *filter*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mask = df[df_atleti_cadiz['year'].eq(2021) | df_atleti_cadiz['month'].eq(1) | df_atleti_cadiz['day'].eq(31)]
df_atleti_cadiz_match = df_atleti_cadiz[mask]
```

This currently reads as:

- Year is 2021 OR Month is 1 OR Day is 31....

Do you perhaps mean to use `&` instead of `|`?

Comment: I will change for "&"