# How to convert year, month, day, hour/minute columns into a single datetime column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following data format with different columns for year, month, day, and hour_minute (the first two digits are hour and the last two digits are minutes). How do I create a new column in datetime format by combining all of these existing columns?

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | HOUR_MINUTE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | 1 | 15 | 0010 |
| 2015 | 1 | 2 | 0020 |
| 2015 | 1 | 15 | 0045 |
| 2015 | 1 | 15 | 2110 |
| 2015 | 10 | 21 | 2359 |

I have tried the following but have no luck. Thank you for your advise your advise.

```
df["new_column"]= pd.to_datetime(df[["YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY","HOUR_MINUTE"]])
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19350806/10197418

Answer (score 1):

You need to split HOUR_MINUTE column to HOUR and MINUTE

```
df["HOUR"] = df["HOUR_MINUTE"].str[0:2]
df["MINUTE"] = df.pop("HOUR_MINUTE").str[2:4]
df["new_column"] = pd.to_datetime(df[["YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY", "HOUR", "MINUTE"]], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   YEAR  MONTH  DAY HOUR MINUTE          new_column
0  2015      1   15   00     10 2015-01-15 00:10:00
1  2015      1    2   00     20 2015-01-02 00:20:00
2  2015      1   15   00     45 2015-01-15 00:45:00
3  2015      1   15   21     10 2015-01-15 21:10:00
4  2015     10   21   23     59 2015-10-21 23:59:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply on entire df if you have only year,month and hour_minute columns like this

```
df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(''.join(row.values.astype(str)), format="%Y%m%d%H%M") ,axis=1)
Out[198]: 
0   2015-11-05 00:10:00
1   2015-01-20 02:00:00
2   2015-11-05 04:05:00
3   2015-11-05 21:10:00
4   2015-10-21 23:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**if there are other columns as well then just select the required columns then apply**

```
df[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR_MINUTE']].apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(''.join(row.values.astype(str)), format="%Y%m%d%H%M") ,axis=1)
Out[201]: 
0   2015-11-05 00:10:00
1   2015-01-20 02:00:00
2   2015-11-05 04:05:00
3   2015-11-05 21:10:00
4   2015-10-21 23:59:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**if you want new_column to be assigned to df then**

```
df['new_column'] = df[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR_MINUTE']].apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(''.join(row.values.astype(str)), format="%Y%m%d%H%M") ,axis=1)
df
Out[205]: 
   YEAR  MONTH  DAY HOUR_MINUTE          new_column
0  2015      1   15        0010 2015-11-05 00:10:00
1  2015      1    2        0020 2015-01-20 02:00:00
2  2015      1   15          45 2015-11-05 04:05:00
3  2015      1   15        2110 2015-11-05 21:10:00
4  2015     10   21        2359 2015-10-21 23:59:00
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggested script**

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': ['2015', '2015', '2015', '2015', '2015'],
                   'MONTH': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '10'],
                   'DAY': ['15', '2', '15', '15', '21'],
                   'HOUR_MINUTE': ['0010', '0020', '0045', '2110', '2359']
                   })

df1['FMT'] = df1.agg('-'.join(['{0[%s]}'%c for c in df1.columns]).format, axis=1)
df1['FMT'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['FMT'], format='%Y-%m-%d-%H%M')

print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
   YEAR MONTH DAY HOUR_MINUTE                 FMT
0  2015     1  15        0010 2015-01-15 00:10:00
1  2015     1   2        0020 2015-01-02 00:20:00
2  2015     1  15        0045 2015-01-15 00:45:00
3  2015     1  15        2110 2015-01-15 21:10:00
4  2015    10  21        2359 2015-10-21 23:59:00
```