# Change the the year based on month in a datafram in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset called weather and it contains one column 'Date' that looks like this.

| Date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-02-04 |
| 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-04-02 |
| 2020-04-03 |
| 2020-04-04 |
| 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-06-01 |
| 2020-07-01 |
| 2020-08-01 |
| 2020-09-01 |
| 2020-10-01 |
| 2020-11-01 |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-06-01 |
| 2020-07-01 |
| 2020-08-01 |
| 2020-09-01 |
| 2020-10-01 |
| 2020-11-01 |
| 2020-12-01 |
| 2020-01-01 |

The problem is the year is always 2020 when it should be 2020, 2021, and 2022.

The desired column looks like this

| Date |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2020-01-02 |
| 2020-02-01 |
| 2020-02-04 |
| 2020-03-01 |
| 2020-04-01 |
| 2020-04-02 |
| 2020-04-03 |
| 2020-04-04 |
| 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-06-01 |
| 2020-07-01 |
| 2020-08-01 |
| 2020-09-01 |
| 2020-10-01 |
| 2020-11-01 |
| 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-04-01 |
| 2021-05-01 |
| 2021-06-01 |
| 2021-07-01 |
| 2021-08-01 |
| 2021-09-01 |
| 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-11-01 |
| 2021-12-01 |
| 2022-01-01 |

Each year's last month is not necessarily 12, but the new year starts with month 01.

Here is my code:

```
month = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']
for i in range(len(weather['Date'])):
    year = 2022
    for j in range(len(month)):
        if weather['Date'][i][5:7] == '01':
            weather['Date'][i] = weather['Date'][i].apply(lambda x: 'year' + x[5:])
```

Is there any suggestion for fixing my code and getting the desired column?

Comment: Do u have one row of data for every month from 2020-1-1 ?

Comment: Do you mean `year += 1`?

Comment: @AminS Thanks for pointing that out! No, there are multiple rows for every month, and I have modified my question.

Comment: @Sheldon Yes, it should be year += 1. But there are multiple rows for each month and it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- Turn the date strings in column `Date` into datetime, using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and apply [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and chain [`Series.dt.day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html).
- Since each *negative* value (i.e. "day") in our `Series` will represent the start of a new year, let's apply [`Series.lt(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) to turn all values below `0` into `True` and the rest into `False`.
- At this stage, we chain [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to end up with a `Series` containing `0, ..., 1, ..., 2`. These will be the values that need to be added to the year `2020` to achieve the correct years.
- Now, finally, we can create the correct dates by passing `(new_year = year + addition), month, day` again to `pd.to_datetime` (cf. this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131/18470692)).

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=(df['Date'].dt.year 
                                       + df['Date'].diff().dt.days.lt(0).cumsum()), 
                                 month=df['Date'].dt.month, 
                                 day=df['Date'].dt.day))

df['Date']

0    2020-01-01
1    2020-01-02
2    2020-02-01
3    2020-02-04
4    2020-03-01
5    2020-04-01
6    2020-04-02
7    2020-04-03
8    2020-04-04
9    2020-05-01
10   2020-06-01
11   2020-07-01
12   2020-08-01
13   2020-09-01
14   2020-10-01
15   2020-11-01
16   2021-01-01
17   2021-02-01
18   2021-04-01
19   2021-05-01
20   2021-06-01
21   2021-07-01
22   2021-08-01
23   2021-09-01
24   2021-10-01
25   2021-11-01
26   2021-12-01
27   2022-01-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You don't *need* to convert to datetime, of course. You can also recreate the date strings, leaving off from the following line:

```
df['Date'].str[5:7].astype(int).diff().lt(0).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @ouroboros1, but using `numpy` to get the number of years to add to each date, and then `pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=...)` for the addition.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
s = df['Date'].values
y = np.r_[0, (s[:-1] > s[1:]).cumsum()]
```

At this point, it would be tempting to do:

```py
df['Date'] += y * pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
```

But then we would get a warning: `PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized.`

So instead, we group by number of years to add, and add the relevant offset to all the dates in the group.

```py
def add_years(g):
    return g['Date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=g['y'].iloc[0])

df['Date'] = df.assign(y=y).groupby('y', sort=False, group_keys=False).apply(add_years)
```

This is reasonably fast (4.25 ms for 1000 rows and 10 distinct `y` values), and, for other situations than yours, is a bit more general than @ouroboros1's answer:

1. It handles date changes due to leap year (not present in your example where all dates are on the first of a month, but if one of the dates was '2020-02-29' and we try to add 1 year to it using the construct `dt = df['Date'].dt; pd.to_datetime(dict(year=dt.year + y, month=dt.month, ...)`, then we'd get a `ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for month`).
2. It preserves any time of day and timezone information (again, not in your case, but in the general case one would retain those).